# Low AdMob match rate

Tags: android, admob, ads

So I just published an app to Google Play with interstitial and rewarded ads. So far I haven't seen my match rate go above 0.30%. The app works perfectly with test ads so I'm pretty confident the issue isn't with my implementation. Using logcat I found pretty much all requests failing with error code 3, aka no ads available.

I have no issues detected in the policy centre. I've double checked my store listing has contains ads enable.  I also added an app-ads.txt and a privacy policy in hopes that might somehow help but alas.
I read that it might just take a few days to start increasing working correctly but the app has been out 4 days with no change whatsoever.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was convinced there was some issue causing the lack of matches but no just like every other question about low match rates turns out all I had to do was wait. After a few days the match rate increased to about 80%. If you also have this issue learn from me and don't worry about it, just give it time.

Comment: Hey Edward, I have some apps for certain country and there was a just like 10 regular user, I have analytics and it says it gains 10 usd on each day, after 20 days match rate is 0, and there's no shown even the high request count. Is it problem or should I wait?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem too. I install the apk to the device ( very same apk which I have published on Google Play Store ), test ads if they work, surprisingly they do. However when I download the very same apk file from Google Play Store no ads show up. It's been more than a week by now and still match rate is as yours. I don't know if the problem is me not linking the app in admob to Google Play Store. Have you linked your admob app to Google Play Store?

edit: From what I understand after searching this thing forever, there is no problem on our end. Admob just requires requests so it can build up its network and start showing ads.